# 10 GB files in home folder due to hidden files

Tags: 13.04, home-directory, disk-usage, hidden-files

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

My home folder is full of hidden files like `.Xauthority.XTMZZW`, `.Xauthority.VEBCZW`, `.goutputstream-0H5NTW` and some of these files are uninstalled software related files but not all.

All these files (including documents, desktop) occupied 13.5 GB space of home folder.

How can I remove unnecessary hidden files?

Answer (score 5):

- select and shift delete from Nautilus
- `rm ~/*goutputstream*` from command line

Answer (score 0):

Backup /home including hidden files before doing anything. Then if you you delete something you should not, you have a way to restore it.

My /home is 2GB. And of that 1.5GB is .wine for Windows Picasa. I have all data folders like Documents, Downloads etc in a data partition on another drive. And some data folders like Firefox & Thunderbird that are hidden also are in my data partitions.